# When I change axis position ggplot stops axis label rotation

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Basically what is says in the subject line. The following code produces a plot with a horizontal y label:

```
require(ggplot2)
silly.plott <- data.frame(silly = c(1,2,3,4,5), plott = c(1,2,3,4,5))
ggplot(silly.plott, aes(x = silly, y = plott))+
    geom_point()+
    theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image: horizontal axis lable]

But when I move the y axis to the left side the labels turn vertical!

```
ggplot(silly.plott, aes(x = silly, y = plott))+
    geom_point()+
    scale_y_continuous(position = "right")+
    theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image: axis on right, vertical label :(]

This feels like such a silly problem and I'm positive I'm just missing something obvious. Plz help me.

Comment: This seems like an issue. I would submit the issue to https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `.right` to the `axis.title.y`:

```
ggplot(silly.plott, aes(x = silly, y = plott))+
geom_point()+
scale_y_continuous(position = "right")+
theme(axis.title.y.right = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5))
```

(https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS.md)

Comment: I knew there had to be a simple solution. Thanks!